# Struts2 Spring autowire="byType"

Tags: java, spring, struts2, autowired

I am using struts2 with spring. In my `struts.properties` file i have

```
struts.objectFactory = spring
struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire = type
```

I have a class like

```
public class JdbcDaoSupportMyDao extends JdbcDaoSupport implements myjdbcDao 
{//......
 //......
}
```

I have an entry in my applicationContext.xml like

```
<bean id = "jdbcdaobeanentry" class="Spring_Ingrtn.JdbcDaoSupportMyDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

Now when i am having a setter/getter like

```
private myjdbcDao jdbcsup; 

public myjdbcDao getJdbcsup() {
  return jdbcsup;
}
public void setJdbcsup(myjdbcDao jdbcsup) {
  this.jdbcsup = jdbcsup;
}
```

It doesn't work ,it throws a `NullPointerException`

Why is this so, when i have mapped 
`struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire = type`
in my `struts.properties` file.

Shouldn't it map to my Interface (i.e. ) ?

Comment: i believe this JdbcDaoSupportMyDao part of spring handing DB operation.The s2 part is only responsible for creating S2 specific things like Action instance/interceptors/results type for others part S2 is not in action

Answer (score 0):

change

`struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire = type`

to

`struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire = auto`

i.e set the auto wire property to auto and let the container decide the best way to decide the wiring policy

Comment: but shouldn't struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire = type

Comment: but shouldn't struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire = type worked,i mean thatz what byType should do....isn't it..???